# What are the potential tradeoffs for lower down Cyclomatic Complexity

Tags: tools, cyclomatic-complexity

Since high Cyclomatic Complexity is harmful, and it would be beneficial to lower it down by creating sub functions. However, it might lead to a long calling queue and lead to some super nested function that would also let the other programmers feel hard to read.

What would be the beneficial solution or where should we set the bottom line for the depth of calling queue? Is there any metrics or tools to test the calling depth of a function?

Any help or idea is appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43165/discussion-on-question-by-jiahang-li-what-are-the-potential-tradeoffs-for-lower).

Answer (score 6):

Extracting code to sub-functions does *not* lower the cyclomatic complexity of a program. It may of course lower the the cyclomatic complexity of an individual function if some complexity is extracted to a separate function, but this just moves the complexity around, which doesn't improve your program in itself.

A high cyclomatic complexity of a function *could* be a warning sign that the function is written in a overly convoluted way. If this is the case, you should consider if the logic could be simplified.

Of course code may be complex because the problem it solves is complex. You should look for *accidental complexity*, complexity which is not needed. A typical example:

```
bool isZero = false;
if (x==0) {
   isZero = true;
} else if (x > 0 || x < 0) {
   isZero = false;
} else {
   Logger.LogError("Invalid value of x");
   throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

The way to fix this accidental complexity is not to extract it to a seperate function, but rather to rewrite it as:

```
bool isZero = x==0;
```

Comment: The complexity (size) of the overall program is, in general, controlled by the complexity (size) of the problem to be solved.  This is before the human tendency to complicate the hell out of everything, because it is more fun to make a mess than clean one up, is taken into account.  The purpose of abstraction (moving things to sub-functions) is to make the pieces easier to develop, test, and manage, which reduces the overall effort required to develop, test, and manage the whole thing.  This is CS 101.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm That's actually a very good explanation of the concept of *essential complexity vs. accidental complexity.*

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Are you equaling complexity with size (line count)?

Comment: Nice answer, but I especially love your random `throw new FileNotFoundException();` line :)

Comment: I agreed with your argument that adding private function won't lower down the CCN of a class, but that's no the measurement module we should choose, but instead a function base would be more beneficial.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova, no, what I am saying is that, IN THE REAL WORLD, complexity and size frequently go hand-in-hand.  I am also drawing a very strong line between "complexity" (an inherent attribute) and "complicatedness" (what happened when Marketing got their paws all over the project spec and added forty pounds of bells and whistles).  "Complex" is an adjective.  "Complicated" is the past tense of a transitive verb, as in "This was a simple system until Joe complicated the frack out of everything."

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: I disagree with this distinction. Accidental complexity means a program is more complex than necessary to fulfill its requirements. Whether the requirements include "bells and whistles" (a subjective opinion) is beside the point.

Answer (score 5):

Is high cyclomatic complexity harmful?  You state this as if it were some self-evident fact, but it's important to keep in mind that in many cases, the real-world problem that you're modeling in your code is a complex problem.

The only time I've heard the claim that cyclomatic complexity is something to be minimized (or something people talk about at all, in fact,) is in the context of unit testing.  If that's the right context for your question, James Coplien puts it better than I could:

> I had a client in northern Europe where the developers were required to have 40% code coverage for Level 1 Software Maturity, 60% for Level 2 and 80% for Le
>   vel 3, while some were aspiring to 100% code coverage. No problem! You’d think that a reasonably complex procedure with branches and loops would have provided a challenge, but it’s just a matter of *divide et impera*. Large functions for 
>   which 80% coverage was impossible were broken down into many small functions for 
>   which 80% coverage was trivial. This raised the overall corporate measure of maturity of its teams in one year, because you will certainly get what you 
>   reward. Of course, this also meant that functions no longer encapsulated algorithms. It was no longer possible to reason about the execution context of a 
>   line of code in terms of the lines that precede and follow it in execution, since those lines of code are no longer adjacent to the one you are concerned about. That sequence transition now took place across a polymorphic function call — a hyper-galactic GOTO. But if all you’re concerned about is branch coverage, it doesn’t matter.
>
> - *If you find your testers splitting up functions to support the testing process, you’re destroying your system architecture and code comprehension along with it. Test at a coarser level of granularity.*
>
> -- [Why Most Unit Testing Is Waste](http://rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf)

In situations like this it's good to remember a quote famously attributed to Einstein: "Make everything as simple as possible, but not simpler."  Prioritizing secondary metrics like cyclomatic complexity over more important things like code readability is a serious violation of this important guideline.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43152/discussion-on-answer-by-mason-wheeler-what-are-the-potential-tradeoffs-for-lower).

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity is also harmful in the context of *maintenance*.

Comment: @Mason I would like to say the number one impact of super high Cyclomatic Complexity is the readability, followed by maintainability and portability. The higher complexity it gets, it is harder to read and understand and also more likely to be error prone. Plus, as you mentioned CCN is referenced as the minim number of test suite for code. If CCN of a function is over 100, it is untestable.However, we don't have to test each case since some of them are too easy to test. Also, how much code coverage we want also depends the usage frequency and the complexity as my personal prespective.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova - no, cyclomatic complexity is *correlated* to harmful effects in maintenance.  In and of itself it is not a problem -- it is only when code becomes *unnecessarily* complex that it is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Low cyclomatic complexity does not necessarily imply that code is easier to understand, so often trying to lower it in a function just amounts to sweeping complexity under the rug.

I see a lot of people out there advocating for (e.g.) using polymorphism instead of switch/case or chains of if/elif/else or whatever, and while that *is* the right thing sometimes, often that makes it hard to reason about where logic flow is going to jump at any given time. The overall cyclomatic complexity of the program won't change at all, and now the logic is scattered over multiple files instead of being all in one place.

Long functions with lots of branching aren't necessarily a bad thing. Implementation details often matter when reading and writing code, so hiding them too aggressively can make it hard to understand the underlying processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large method, simply breaking down the method into smaller units may not add any additional benefit other than tweaking metrics.

Complexity can be fixed by:

- Refactoring
- Redesigning

Sometimes refactoring is appropriate.  We have a complex method that does five things, it makes sense to refactor into 1 main method that calls 5 sub methods. This should make the code easier to understand and test.   We may be able to eliminate some lines of code but in the end we probably have the same amount of the lines of code that we started with. These type of efforts look good at first glance and may produce better metrics against your code base, but overall the value added may be smaller than expected.  You have to determine if the break down is appropriate.  Obviously breaking down a large method into 10s or 100s of sub or nested calls may introduce a cobra effect where your good intentions made things worse.  You want to avoid that.

Sometimes we have a method that is too complex for plain old refactoring or break down into smaller chunks.  In that case, we may need a redesign.  A redesign may introduce new design pattern(s) and/or new classes that simplify the code.  So, instead of 1000 lines of code, the end result of the re-design is 200 lines of code.  These are much more difficult endeavors, but provides more value from a metric standpoint and from a overall code standpoint.  Less code, less complex.

Tradeoffs are always time and effort.  Sometimes the budget can only allow for small refactoring as in the first example.  Other times a complex overhaul as in case 2.

Developers should always monitor the health of the code base by policing themselves, providing peer reviews, and official code reviews as code is added to the solution.  This will keep the complexity at a manageable level.